# How to use surround.vim to quote a single character?

Tags: plugin-vim-surround

I'm a user of the `surround.vim` plugin that lets me surround words with quotes, brackets, etc.

I'm facing an issue with surrounding a single character with e.g. quotes, when the character is adjacent to other characters. Thus, I cannot use `ysw"` to quote the single character.

How can I operate on a single character? I'm used to using `x` to delete a single character, but I'm not familiar with a motion like `w` that describes a single character.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faster than visual mode: `ysl"`

You can use both text-objects and motions with any operator, and `hjkl` are motions!

Note that according to `:help x`, the command `x` is equivalent to `dl`, while `X` is equivalent to `dh`. They have a kind of paradoxical definition that turns out to be nicely intuitive in practice.

The reason they work this is both are `exclusive` motions, which means the last character of the selection is not included. This "last character" is always determined relative to the buffer end: in other words, characters closer to `G$` are "later" than characters closer to `gg0`! So `yl` will only yank the character you're on, while `yh` yanks the previous character. This holds for any operator, including the surround version given at the top.

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn’t `l` affect the next character and not the character under the cursor?

Comment: Press `vl` and realize that the character under the cursor is highlighted; `l` in this case is a sort of exclusive motion that includes only the current char. In fact, `x` is equivalent to `dl`

Comment: Shouldn’t `dh` be equivalent to `dl` then?

Comment: @Shuzheng i’m sure, but (somewhat paradoxically) I wouldnt expect so: probably equivalent to `X`

Comment: @Shuzheng i just checked the docs and confirmed my above comment.

Comment: Nice, what did you search for to find such information?

Comment: See my edits—its a combo of `:help x` and `:help l` and `:help exclusive`

Answer (score 1):

`S` in visual mode with an argument wraps the selected text. So:

1. Put your cursor on the character you want to quote.
2. Press `v` to select it.
3. Press `S"` to quoto.

Comment: how did you get so good at vim?